# How to fix `#USE_PROJECT_JDK` when opening gradle project in IDEA?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Everytime I open a gradle project, if I use default settings, it has an invalid gradle JVM:

[image]

I have to fix it by selecting another valid JDK every time, since the configuration here is just "for current project":

[image]

I can't find a way to setup a global or default option for all projects.

Do I missing anything?

Comment: As far as I know this is only project based and should be configured in the  `Project Settings ` ->  `Project ` menu (`F4` on the project folder on windows) ... there you can specify the default sdk. This way it would work a little better.

If you are not happy with that you may should issue a ticket at: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com as feature request or usablity issue.

Comment: Could you describe steps how you open/import/create a new project?

Comment: Thanks guys, I found the problem and see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

In my system, openjdk 11.0.1 is installed by mistake and be my default jdk (which means I run `java -version` in terminal will print `11.0.1`). When I open an existing gradle project, I used to go to the dir from command line and type `idea .`. IDEA detects openjdk 11.0.1 and uses it as the project jdk. Since I don't really want to use this version of JDK, I deleted its configuration from IDEA(not from the OS).

In order to make IDEA uses JDK 1.8 by default, my solution is to delete openjdk 11.0.1 from system completed and make sure JDK 1.8 is the default. Now everything is OK.

PS: I still think it's be great to have a way to setup default JDK version for all new projects, currently we can also set for individual projects.

Comment: `PS: I still think it's be great to have a way to setup default JDK version for all new projects, currently we can also set for individual projects.` you can do it via File | Other Settings... | Structure for New Projects... See [IDE-level (global) settings and structure](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#ide-level).

Comment: @Andrey Yes! Thank you so much!